# custom DMatch object for NNDR type error?

Tags: image-stitching

d1,d2 are descriptor

```
matches=[]
for i in range(len(d1)-1):
    dist= (np.linalg.norm(d1[i] - d2[i])) / (np.linalg.norm(d1[i] - d2[i+1]))
    #print (dist,"  ")
    if dist <= 0.8:
        k=k+1
        matches.extend(cv2.DMatch(i,i,dist))
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, f1, img2, f2,matches, None, flags=2)
```

TypeError: 'cv2.DMatch' object is not iterable

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following changing

matches.append(cv2.DMatch(i,i,dist)) but following is not working

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, f1, img2, f2,matches, None, flags=2)